# How do I inject Heroku's PORT value into a dotnet core 6.0 web api?

Tags: heroku, .net-core, environment-variables

I'm *not* using Docker. Rather, I'm trying to use the [jincod/dotnetcore](https://github.com/jincod/dotnetcore-buildpack) buildpack. However, I need a way to tell dotnet to use Heroku's port number environment variable, and I just don't see a good way of doing that here.

In my `Program.cs` file, I added the following:

```cs
builder.Services.AddHttpsRedirection(options =>
{
    options.HttpsPort = int.TryParse(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT"), out var p) ? p : null;
});
```

which actually *sort of* works in that I'm able to obtain the port number value from Heroku, but this just redirects me to `myapp.heroku.com:1234` from `myapp.heroku.com` and is still not working as expected.

I see in the `launchSettings.json` file, in the `profiles` section, there is an `applicationUrl` that shows two urls, one for https and one for http, both of which have port numbers specified. I think if I can overwrite those port numbers this might work, but I don't know how to inject that environment variable into the `launchSettings.json` file from Heroku. Anyone know a good way of doing this? Or am I even on the right track here?

Answer (score 4):

I believe if you add the following before the https redirection middleware you won't need to pass any configuration into `UseHttpsRedirection`

```cs
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });
```

You can get the port variable and bind it. If you are using dotnet 6 minimal APIs you can do this.

```cs
var port = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT") ?? "3100";
app.Run("http://0.0.0.0:" + port);
```

You'll need to add `"https_port": 443` to your appsettings.json or set the environment variable `ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT` to 443 in heroku. You can see this in action here.

https://github.com/TerribleDev/dotnet-mvc-test

https://tp-aspnet-tst.herokuapp.com/

If you are using older versions than 6 you can do something like this...

```cs
public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) {
            var builder = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .ConfigureKestrel(a =>
                {
                    a.AddServerHeader = false;
                });
            var port = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("PORT");
            if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(port)) {
                builder.UseUrls("http://*:" + port);
            }
            return builder;
        }
```